# Hosting multiple sites

Tags: plugins, multisite

I need to create 250 basic wordpress sites on one dedicated server with cpanel on it.

The domain names of the sites are different. Themes will be different. Content will be different.

Is there a wordpress plugin for this? Should I use one wordpress instance for this?

Should i use one database or multiple databases? Again is there a prod ready plugin for this ?

Answer (score 1):

If these sites are going to be distinctly different entities, then you are going to want to set up individual sites with individual databases. Especially if these are for different clients.

The domain names will be handled by the hosting company and there should be something in cPanel that will facilitate that.

Comment: They are for the same client. Do you want to manage 250 password? and config?

Comment: Then WordPress in the MU configuration would be a better option then. Just keep in mind your themes will be available to all sites and that plugins fall under three categories now: Must-Use, Network, and Site-Specific.

You can here more [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration)

Comment: what do u mean by MU configuration? Not sure if this answers my question.

Comment: Multisite. It used to be a separate build of WordPress called WordPressMU but a while back they merged the two together. What I wouild recommend is install a brand new copy of WordPress locally on your system. After installation, go into `wp-congfig.php` and add this line `define('MULTISITE', true);` This will turn on network management under Tools